# Removing metadata from an instruction LLVM

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, llvm

Does anyone have any idea how to remove metadata from an instruction in LLVM-IR?

Comment: Take a look at `-strip` pass.

Comment: None of this is helpful, but thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove a specifc kind of metadata from an instruction, use `setMetadata(kind, NULL)`. To remove all the metadata, call `getAllMetadata` first, then iterate over the kinds in the returned collection and remove them via the first method.

Keep in mind that this will not remove the actual MDNode and will not remove any `dbg.declare` or `dbg.value` calls if that's what interests you.